# How can I get the selected values of several radio buttons to be bound to an object (model)?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs

I have an array of objects I am using to render radio button lists using ng-repeat. My question is how can I bind the selected value of each question and bind those to some type of model.
Here is the plunker I have so far, http://plnkr.co/edit/oXr6Un?p=preview but the code just loops through the radio button lists and get the selected values. I truly want that object to be bound and change its properties when the user selects an answer. how can I do this? Please understand I am very new to Angularjs.
Thanks All,
ck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Max said above, you need to set the ng-model on your inputs... However that's not all you need to do.  [I've forked your plunk and updated it to show you something that works](http://plnkr.co/edit/EvTgbb)

A few things to note:

- You didn't need a service to "showAnswers", and you should never have to get values from inputs via JQuery while you're using Angular.
- You needed to add the ng-model in the input, but you need to use `$parent.answer` in the ng-model, because the input was inside of an `ng-repeat` which has it's own child scope.
- You don't need `for=""` on labels that wrap the input they're labeling.

Important Changes:

```
    <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.question.selectedAnswer"
         value="{{ answer.answerText }}"  name="quest_{{$parent.$index}}_answers" />{{ answer.answerText }}</label>
    </li>
```

and

```
$scope.selectedAnswers = function(){
   var answers = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(question) {
    answers.push(question.selectedAnswer);
   });
   return answers;
 };
```

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Awesome! my next step is to convert to directives to clean up the html. How can I access $parent from a template? It doesn't seem to work. http://plnkr.co/edit/oXr6Un?p=preview

Comment: Here, I've updated your plunk to work:  http://plnkr.co/edit/gFMISh  ... notice I've moved your selectedAnswers() repeat inside of the QuizController block... also, I've added scope parameters to each directive, for example `scope: { 'question' : '=' }` (which sets up a two way binding between the directive's `$scope.question` and whatever is passed into the `question="???"` attribute. As well as `restrict`'s to restrict those directives to their parents (not really necessary, but I did it just to show you).

Comment: @blesh, I think you can remove the "require: 'question'" and "require: 'quiz'" lines.  These directives aren't trying to access any controllers with those names.  "restrict: 'E'" is required on at least the quiz and question directives, since they are being used as element names.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the ng-model on the input (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.radio). With that, you will get two way data binding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write the directive version: http://plnkr.co/edit/Otikw0fX8rwx2gM8DMMl?p=preview

I streamlined the model.  Each question and its possible answers look like this:

```
{ question: "Why is the sky blue?",
  answerChoices: [ "blah blah 1", "Rayleigh scattering", "blah blah 3" ] },
```

To each such object we will dynamically add an 'answer' element via the radio buttons.  More about that later.

I streamlined the factory.  It simply returns an array of objects:

```
.factory('questionFactory', function() {
  return [
   { question: ...
```

The controller can now simply do this:

```
$scope.questions_and_answers = questionFactory;
```

Now we have our model defined.  Next, I like to think about what directives I'll need, and what the templates and behaviors of each directive will be.  I kept your 3 directives -- quiz, question, answer -- but I renamed answer to possibleAnswer.

As a matter of personal choice, I thought it would be better to have the 'quiz' directive contain the main structure for the questions and answers, so I moved the ng-repeat for the answers out of the question directive's template and into the quiz directive's template.
I also left quiz an element, but I changed question and possibleAnswer to attributes since I personally like to see a more familiar markup structure like
 <li ng-repeat ...> something here </li>
 instead of the unfamiliar
 <li answer ng-repeat ...></li>

```
.directive('quiz', function() {
...
  template:'<ul class="unstyled">' +
    '<li ng-repeat="item in questionsAndAnswers">' + 
      '<span question="{{item.question}}"></span>' +
      '<ul class="unstyled">' + 
        '<li ng-repeat="possibleAnswer in item.answerChoices">' +
          '<span possible-answer="{{possibleAnswer}}" item=item id="{{$parent.$index}}"></span>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
    '</li></ul>'
```

The question directive template now just deals with the question:

```
template:'<strong class="question">{{ question }}</strong>'
```

And the possibleAnswer directive just deals with one possible answer (like you already had):

```
template: '<label><input type="radio" ng-value="possibleAnswer"' + 
    ' ng-model="item.answer" name="q{{id}}" />{{possibleAnswer}}</label>'
```

There's a lot going on in those templates, and to understand what I did, we now need to talk about directive scope inheritance.  I'm using isolated scope for all of the directives -- i.e., `scope: { ... }` -- since that is normally the best choice for reusable components. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502783/dynamic-directives-in-angularjs/13656516#13656516) for other choices.)  The questions and answer choices will not be modified by the directives, so we don't need 2-way binding, only one-way binding (parent scope -> directive scope), so '@' is the appropriate choice:

```
.directive('question', function() {
  ...
  scope: { question: '@' }, 

.directive('possibleAnswer', function() {
  ...
  scope: { possibleAnswer: '@', ... },
```

We need to pass the directives an evaluated copy of the questions and possible answers from the parent scope, so we use the {{}} notation:

```
<span question="{{item.question}}">
<span possible-answer="{{possibleAnswer}}" ...
```

Now for the tricky part.  The radio buttons associated with a single question all need the same name, and as @Max already mentioned, we need 2-way binding back to the parent model for all the radio buttons.  I solved "same name" issue by using one-way binding of a question ID, which is really the ng-repeat question $index:

```
<span possible-answer="{{possibleAnswer}}" id="{{$parent.$index}}" ...>

.directive('possibleAnswer', function() {
  ...
  scope: { id: '@', ... },
  ...
  template: '...<input type="radio" ... name="q{{id}}"...
```

Since we want the same question ID/index (not the answer choice ID/index), we look up the the question scope using $parent and grab its ng-repeat $index, hence $parent.$index.  An alternative would be to add an 'id' property to each object in the main model (as you have) and pass that to the directive:

```
<span possible-answer="..." id="{{item.id}}" ...>
```

(Actually, since below you'll see that we're passing 'item' into the directive, such an id property would come along for free, and hence there would not be any need for "id='...'" in the template.)  I prefer to make the model as simple as possible.  Since we're using an array of objects, the array index (ng-repeat $index) is sufficient, so I did not use an id property on the main model.

To obtain 2-way data binding, we need to use '='.  We want to bind to a new 'answer' property that we're going to dynamically add to the objects in the main model (I mentioned this earlier).  So we need a reference to the appropriate object in the model, while we're looping through the answer choices.  We then assign this new, dynamic property to ng-model:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in questionsAndAnswers">' +   // pass this 'item' to possibleAnswer
   ...
   '<ul ..>' + 
      '<li ng-repeat="possibleAnswer in item.answerChoices">' +
           <span possible-answer="{{possibleAnswer}}" item=item ...">

.directive('possibleAnswer', function() {
  ...
  scope: { item: '=', ... },
  ...
  template: '...<input type="radio" ... ng-model="item.answer" ...'  // new property
```

NOTE: 'ng-value' should be used instead of 'value', according to a Disqus comment on the [input radio API page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.radio).

```
template: '...<input type="radio" ng-value="possibleAnswer" ...
```

For the quiz element directive, I think the component is more reusable if you pass in the model, rather than assuming that a certain scope property exists in the parent scope, hence:

```
<quiz questions-and-answers=questions_and_answers></quiz>
```

Since the possibleAnswer directive needs to modify the model, we also have to use 2-way binding here as well, hence '=':

```
.directive('quiz', function() {
  ...
  scope: { questionsAndAnswers: '='},
```

Lastly, the controller:  I removed function selectedAnswer() and slightly modified the ng-repeat in index.html to obtain the same functionality:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in questions_and_answers">
   A{{$index}}: {{item.answer}}
```

So the controller is nice and thin (a recommended best practice) -- one line of code.

There was no use of jQuery, so I removed it.  (I didn't see any use of bootstrap.js either, and it was throwing an error, so I removed that too.)

This was a great exercise for me, thanks for the OP.  (Sorry if this answer is way too long.  I got carried away, but writing it all down helped clarify a few things for me.)